# BlueZ BTGATT-client.py WriteValue

Tags: python, pi-3b+, bluetooth, bluez, dbus

I had a successful attempts with `BlueZ-5.50 > test > example-gatt-client.py` with ESP32 set as HeartRate Sensor Server.I am able to read from ESP32 which i modified to suit the BlueZ example.

However i have a doubt. What if i need to send some byte or string to ESP32 from the existing example.I wrote in such manner (a simple function to see whether it throws an error):

```
def write_val():

value = 0x50

#Write to a UUID
cg_ctrl_pt_chrc.WriteValue(value,reply_handler=body_sensor_val_cb,
                                error_handler=generic_error_cb,
                                dbus_interface=GATT_CHRC_IFACE)
```

I am still new & learning Dbus & Python.

*OS* - Raspbian Stretch

Comment: Hi guys/girls any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The examples in the BlueZ test directory use the dbus-python library which is not the best of python libraries according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbusExamples.

A library from that page is pydbus https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/ which seems to work well with the BlueZ DBus API for a GATT client.

I don't have an ESP32 or Heart Rate Sensor, so I will do an example with a BBC micro:bit and hopefully it will be easy to modify to your needs.

The BlueZ DBus API documentation is available at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

Some useful things to know to get you started:

1. The Dbus service for bluez is called `org.bluez`
2. The Bluetooth adapter on a Raspberry Pi normally has the DBus object path of `/org/bluez/hci0`
3. The DBus Object path to a device is the adapter path plus the mac address prepended by 'dev_' and the semi-colons replaced with underscores. i.e. 'DE:82:35:E7:43:BE' would be found at `/org/bluez/hci0/dev_DE_82_35_E7_43_BE`

This script assumes that the device has already been paired with Raspberry Pi. As the pairing is a one-off provisioning step, it makes things simplier to do it manually. I usually use `bluetoothctl` on the command line.

```py
import pydbus
from gi.repository import GLib

# Setup of device specific values
dev_id = 'DE:82:35:E7:43:BE'
btn_a_uuid = 'e95dda90-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8'
temp_reading_uuid = 'e95d9250-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8'
temp_period_uuid = 'e95d1b25-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8'

# DBus object paths
bluez_service = 'org.bluez'
adapter_path = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_path = f"{adapter_path}/dev_{dev_id.replace(':', '_')}"

bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
adapter = bus.get(bluez_service, adapter_path) 
device = bus.get(bluez_service, device_path)

# Assume device has been paired already so can use connect
device.Connect()
# Get commands and properties available
print(dir(adapter))
print(dir(device))
```

To read and write you need to find the path to the characteristic which is a little more work. Typically you know the UUID of the characteristic you are interested in so to get the value from button A on a BBC micro:bit it would be:

```py
mngr = bus.get(bluez_service, '/')

def get_characteristic_path(dev_path, uuid):
    mng_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mng_objs:
        chr_uuid = mng_objs[path].get('org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1', {}).get('UUID')
        if path.startswith(dev_path) and chr_uuid == uuid:
           return path

char_path = get_characteristic_path(device._path, btn_a_uuid)
btn = bus.get(bluez_service, char_path)
print(btn.ReadValue({}))
# [0]
```

Writing to a characteristic is similar. Here is an example of reading and writing to the Temperature Period on a BBC micro:bit

```py
tmp_period_path = get_characteristic_path(device._path, temp_period_uuid)
tmp_period = bus.get(bluez_service, tmp_period_path)
print(tmp_period.ReadValue({}))
# Result is:
# [232, 3]
# To get it as an integer:
print(int.from_bytes(tmp_period.ReadValue({}), byteorder='little'))
# 1000

# To write a new value of 1500
new_value = int(1500).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')
tmp_period.WriteValue(new_value, {})
print(tmp_period.ReadValue({}))
# [220, 5]
device.Disconnect()
```

If you want to run this in an eventloop with notifications from the remote device then remove the disconnect above and add the following code:

```py
temp_reading_path = get_characteristic_path(device._path, temp_reading_uuid)
temp = bus.get(bluez_service, temp_reading_path)

# Enable eventloop for notifications
def temp_handler(iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
    """Notify event handler for temperature"""
    if 'Value' in prop_changed:
        print(f"Temp value: {as_int(prop_changed['Value'])} \u00B0C")

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
temp.onPropertiesChanged = temp_handler
temp.StartNotify()
try:
    mainloop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    mainloop.quit()
    temp.StopNotify()
    device.Disconnect()
```

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thank you ukBaz :) . I saw your example and gave a try. Correct me if i am wrong, this code will run only once right.So it does not do '.mainloop()' or is it part of 'connect();'

Secondly, let say if i need to do 'Notify' or 'Indicate' , where and how to refer? I need to get sensor data from BLE Server which will change maybe every minutes.

Comment: Then my next action will be moving the data to AWS server (which is not relevant here)  but letting you know.

Comment: Yes the original example just ran through once without a mainloop. 
Depending how frequently you wanted to read the sensor, you could put the original script in a `crontab`.

I have extended the example to include a mainloop and notifications.
With the notify example, you could change the notify handler to send the data to AWS server rather than printing as in my example does.

Comment: Thanks again for the help ukBaz.I was from embedded systems background (mostly C/C++) so working alongside with Python is a bit..well..feel unconnected. And dbus was whole new topic for me. Sure. I will give a try and approach you back if need any help. Thank You!

Comment: Oh forgot : I tried the given example and sometimes it throws 'Software Reset Occured'. I this case how to check whether bluetooth has connected or not? Just want to have a quick reference with you. Sorry ukBaz

Comment: @R.M.S.Sundram  If you have `bluetoothctl` running in another terminal on the Raspberry Pi it will report what the changes in status are of the Bluetooth.

Comment: Hi again ukBaz.I tried your suggestion. It seems able to communicate with ESP32.However there's 1 thing i don't understand. When i sent  data int8 from RPI to ESP32, i get inverted question mark in ESP32.I checked on the ESP32 terminal baud and were correct. Does it has to do with casting an int data to string or else?

Comment: @R.M.S.Sundram is the int value 191 or 0xbf by any chance? If you do `chr(0xbf)` you get `'¿'`. I often see things like this when printing bytes of data to the screen. Could it be that you are seeing?

Comment: Nope i didn't do any conversion nor cast. I did : new_value = int(1500).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little') \ tmp_period.WriteValue(new_value, {}) like from the example. What if i need to conv from byte to string? This data is stored in array right by default  right ? Thanks @ukBaz

Comment: Are you able to share details (or a link) to your particular hardware setup or what code you have running on the ESP32? Otherwise it is very difficult to answer your questions.

Comment: Sure.I use this example for quick data transfer from RPI to ESP32. I modified the pydbus example to match the same UUID for ESP32 https://platformio.org/lib/show/1841/ESP32%20BLE%20Arduino

Comment: I've posted a new answer after see the ESP32 code. Can you confirm you have got the ESP32 to do its thing using a phone or bluetoothctl?

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! It's working.I am able to send from RPI to ESP32.  However the ' device_path = f"{adapter_path}/dev_{dev_id.replace(':', '_')}" ' is throwing an error. Another question : Are we able to do discovery and connect using device name only? Or should we write another script to get this? Thanks very-very much ukBaz. I seriously appreciate your help.Now i can see climb up ladder for Dbus & GLib

Comment: Good news it is working!   Don't for get to accept or edit an answer so it is a reference for others. What version of Python are you using? f-string formatting was first in Python 3.6.  For the discovery question, I've answered a question very similar to that at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106771/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-only-bluetooth-audio-devices/114173#114173

Comment: Hi again. As i have successfully sent string to ESP32, i am stuck at the second apart of the code especially on this portion : `mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()`which puts error as `NameError: name 'mainloop' is not defined `  &  `(150).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable` . I am using Python Python 3.5.3.

Comment: Another thing is in `if 'Value' in prop_changed:` , does this same **value** can be used to Notify say button press status? The Python terms are kinda making me spin haha

Answer (score 0):

I am posting another answer to see if this fits better given that you have posted the link which has the code you are using at the other end of the link:

https://platformio.org/lib/show/1841/ESP32%20BLE%20Arduino

Looking at the BLE_write.ino, my understanding is that if you write text to "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8" the ESP32 will display the text on its console.

```py
import pydbus
from time import sleep

# Setup of device specific values
dev_id = 'DE:82:35:E7:43:BE'
# BBC micro:bit text display characteristic
# txt_uuid = 'E95D93EE-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8'
# ESP32 BLE_write.ino text characteristic 
txt_uuid = 'beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8'

txt_to_send = 'This is a test'

# DBus object paths
bluez_service = 'org.bluez'
adapter_path = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_path = f"{adapter_path}/dev_{dev_id.replace(':', '_')}"
# Get adapter and device objects
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
adapter = bus.get(bluez_service, adapter_path) 
device = bus.get(bluez_service, device_path)

# Assume device has been paired already so can use connect
device.Connect()

# Wait for the remote device to resolve its services
while not device.ServicesResolved:
    sleep(0.5)

mngr = bus.get(bluez_service, '/')

def get_characteristic_path(dev_path, uuid):
    """Get DBus object path for Characteristic UUID"""
    mng_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mng_objs:
        chr_uuid = mng_objs[path].get('org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1', {}).get('UUID')
        if path.startswith(dev_path) and chr_uuid == uuid.casefold():
           return path

txt_path = get_characteristic_path(device._path, txt_uuid)
txt_obj = bus.get(bluez_service, txt_path)
# Turn text into 
new_value = [ord(c) for c in txt_to_send]
# Write a new value ensure it is not too long for Bluetooth 
txt_obj.WriteValue(new_value[:19], {})

# Disconnect
device.Disconnect()
```