# Using PyDBUS to read BLE battery service

Tags: raspbian-stretch, bluetooth, bluez, dbus

I tried to read battery service (0x180F) using pydbus and also via term but unable to find, setNotify or read the value.

I tried to `register-service` under `Menu GATT` in Terminal running `Bluetoothctl` but i kind of stuck on the next move.

How to read this service (including through pydbus).I have successfully read other services (Automation IO) but this seems a but different? Correct me if im wrong.

Thank you

*BlueZ-5.50
*Raspbian Stretch

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114150/bluez-btgatt-client-py-writevalue/114175#114175 ? The only difference is the UUID of the characteristic?  Can you show a minimal example of the code you are trying and I'll see if I can spot the issue.

Comment: Hi uKBaz.Once again thanks for the help. For the sake of clarification i used ESP32 

`
#define BatteryService BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x180F) 
BLECharacteristic BatteryLevelCharacteristic(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A19), 

BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
'
BLEDescriptor BatteryLevelDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2901));
`

Comment: Have you tried reading the Battery Service from the ESP32 with nRF Connect (https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile)? You need to prove the ESP32 server is working first before you start writing the RPi end. Put the code snippets in your question using the `edit` button. The formatting doesn't work in the comments.

Comment: Yes i have triend with the nRF Connect. And the answer was it is working

Comment: Excellent! So what does your pydbus code look like? And what error messages are you getting?

Comment: @ukBaz - I used the example that you have mentioned to me from here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555356/bluez-pydbus-2-client-connected-in-hci0/63556387#63556387
I used the same method by accessing to the path (org.bluez and UUID & get the objects) However when you check on `Bluetoothctl`, you cant read the battery UUID because i believe it's specific service that need to be registered?

Comment: And it is 00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb you are trying to read and not 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb?

Comment: I tried both but no success. What intrigues me is that why i can't access Battery Service just like other services do? Even in Blue-Z.

Comment: You know that `register-service` is not the correct command in `bluetoothctl`? You are sharing so little information and you are not updating the question. I don't know how you expect people to know the answers to these questions with the information you have shared. Looking at the documentation, battery level is just like all the others. It works in nRF Connect so the data coming in is right. So the issue is highly likely to be in how you are using `blutetoothctl` or your Python code but you haven't shared a transcript of your `bluetoothctl` session or your python code. So how can we help?

Comment: A screenshot of the nRF Connect app would be helpful. This is a standard service: Battery service: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml  Battery Level: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml

Comment: @ukBaz Understood the hassle caused.I am typing from Mac and the code is in RPI lite.Will post the code earlier by today.

On the links, thanks for the help. Went through the Bluetooth SIG.

Comment: If your RPi is on the network then enable `ssh` access to the RPi as you can then open a terminal on the RPi from the Mac. This will allow you to more easily copy and paste `bluetoothctl` transcripts etc. You can also `scp` files between the two machines.